# Action with pandas SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, chained-assignment

I try to `delete` some column and convert some value in column with

```
df2.drop(df2.columns[[0, 1, 3]], axis=1, inplace=True)
df2['date'] = df2['date'].map(lambda x: str(x)[1:])
df2['date'] = df2['date'].str.replace(':', ' ', 1)
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])
```

and to all this string I get

```
  df2.drop(df2.columns[[0, 1, 3]], axis=1, inplace=True)
C:/Users/����� �����������/Desktop/projects/youtube_log/filter.py:11: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

What is problem there?

Comment: How did you create `df2`? If you have typed something like `df2 = df1`, this error comes from the fact that `df2` is a slice of `df1` not an entire object itself. Try `df2 = df1.copy()`

Comment: @ysearka `df2 = df[df.id == 30013]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `df2` is a slice of another dataframe.  You need to explicitly copy it with `df2 = df2.copy()` just prior to your attempt to `drop`

Consider the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5), list('abcd'), list('ABCDE'))

df1
```

[image]

Let me assign a slice of `df1` to `df2`

```
df2 = df1[['A', 'C']]
```

[image]

`df2` is now a slice of `df1` and should trigger those pesky `SettingWithCopyWarning`'s if we try to change things in `df2`.  Let's take a look.

```
df2.drop('c')
```

[image]

No problems.  How about:

```
df2.drop('c', inplace=True)
```

There it is:

[image]

The problem is that pandas tries to be efficient and tracks that `df2` is pointing to the same data as `df1`.  It is preserving that relationship.  The warning is telling you that you shouldn't be trying to mess with the original dataframe via the slice.

Notice that when we look at `df2`, row 'c' has been dropped.

```
df2
```

[image]

And looking at `df1` we see that row 'c' is still there.

```
df1
```

[image]

pandas made a copy of `df2` then dropped row 'c'.  This is potentially inconsistent with what our intent may have been considering we made `df2` a slice of and pointing to same data as `df1`.  So pandas is warning us.

To not see the warning, make the copy yourself.

```
df2 = df2.copy()
# or
df2 = df1[['A', 'C']].copy()
```

Comment: Thank you for great explanation!

Comment: if don't want to do a copy and still remove the message, you can set it up: pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

Comment: Can I say to pandas not show message in just that statement? My intent really is remove a row from slice, not original data