# How to add a column to a multi-indexed DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
upper    level1    level2 
lower    name      name
1        Mary      Tom
2        ...       ...
```

What should I do if I want to add another column under `level1`? For example

```
upper    level1       level2 
lower    name    age  name
1        Mary    13   Tom
2        ...    ...    ...
```

I can access data with `df['level1'].loc[:,'name']`, but I don't know how to add/remove a column.

If I just use `df.level1['age']=1`, Python returns a copy warning and nothing changed in the DataFrame:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.insert(1, ('level1', 'age'), pd.Series([13]))
```

Comment: it's so easy and elegant!

Comment: Thanks it works! Could you please explain why my code is incorrect?

Comment: @Arthur see http://stackoverflow.com/a/38147527/2336654 for a good example of what is happening with `SettingWithCopyWarning`.  In your case, `df.level1` is returning a slice or view of `df` and you are trying to alter `df` via the slice.  Pandas will make a copy of `df.level1` and perform the alteration on the copy instead.  Often this isn't what you want and pandas is warning you.

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can use tuple in the assignment:

```
In [11]: df[('level1', 'age')] = 13  # or a Series here, rather than a number

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
  upper level1 level2 level1
  lower   name   name    age
0     1   Mary    Tom     13
1     2    ...    ...     13
```

Comment: Thank you! But could you please tell me why my code is wrong? I'm new to Python.

Comment: @Arthur when doing df.level1 it creates a view which is the subdataframe which has only the level1 columns. Trying to create a new column on the view (with `df.level1['age']=1`) doesn't work, as you can't edit the "view" (it's readonly).