# How to change dataframe column with no warning "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe wich name is "data" with 97230 rows and 4 columns. Name one of columns for example is "A". Also i have some variables: "indVec" - bool series with same index as "data"; valVec - vector with some values.
sum(indVec)=len(indVal)
I am trying to set value for column 'A' in index "indVec" by different ways. But every  time i get this message:

"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)"

Ways, that i am using to set values for 'A' column of dataframe "data":

1. `data.loc[indVec,'A']=valVec`
2. `data.ix[indVec,'A']=valVec`
3. `data.set_value[indVec,'A']=valVec`
4. `data.A[indVec]=valVec`

How can I set value for column 'A' without this message?

Comment: Is `data` a slice of another dataframe? The things you have tried should work.

Comment: You'll need to post raw data and code that reproduces this, if you filtered the df prior to these calls then this warning will be raised

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/38147527/2336654

Comment: Thanks a lot! You were right. "Dataframe.copy()" solved this problem!

Comment: mute all warning. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777951/how-to-suppress-pandas-future-warning