# Pandas: SettingWithCopyWarning, trying to understand how to write the code better, not just whether to ignore the warning

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, slice, chained-assignment

I am trying to change all date values in a spreadsheet's Date column where the year is earlier than 1900, to today's date, so I have a slice.

EDIT: previous lines of code:

```
df=pd.read_excel(filename)#,usecols=['NAME','DATE','EMAIL']
#regex to remove weird characters
df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].str.replace(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\._/-]', '')
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])

sample row in dataframe: name, date, email
[u'Public, Jane Q.\xa0' u'01/01/2016\xa0' u'jqpublic@email.com\xa0']
```

This line of code works.

```
df["DATE"][df["DATE"].dt.year < 1900] = dt.datetime.today()
```

Then, all date values are formatted:

```
df["DATE"] = df["DATE"].map(lambda x: x.strftime("%m/%d/%y"))
```

But I get an error:

> ```
> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
> slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
> http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-
> ```

versus-copy

I have read the documentation and other posts, where using .loc is suggested

The following is the recommended solution:

```
df.loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value
```

but `df["DATE"].loc[df["DATE"].dt.year < 1900] = dt.datetime.today()` gives me the same error, except that the line number is actually the line number after the last line in the script.

I just don't understand what the documentation is trying to tell me as it relates to my example.

I started messing around with pulling out the slice and assigning to a separate dataframe, but then I'm going to have to bring them together again.

Comment: This should give you a good idea of what's going on http://stackoverflow.com/a/38147527/2336654

Comment: it's `df.loc[df["DATE"].dt.year < 1900, "DATA"] = dt.datetime.today()`

Comment: But that code puts the date value in every column in the dataframe for that row. That is why I had changed it to `df["DATE"][df["DATE"]...`

Comment: No. 

And `df.loc[df["DATE"].dt.year < 1900, "DATA"] = dt.datetime.today()` is not  catching the year 1700

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are producing a view when you `df["DATE"]` and subsequently use a selector `[df["DATE"].dt.year < 1900]` and try to assign to it.

`df["DATE"][df["DATE"].dt.year < 1900]` is the view that pandas is complaining about.

Fix it with `loc` like this:

```
df.loc[df.DATE.dt.year < 1900, "DATE"] = pd.datetime.today()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have edited my original question to include the previous lines of code and a sample of data that is a row from the excel file that I am working from.

Comment: Based on print df.is_copy, it is not a copy, the result was None. Does this mean I can suppress the warning?

Comment: @mattrweaver Updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

My thought would be that you could do

```
df.loc[df.DATE.dt.year < 1900, "DATE"] = dt.datetime.today()
df.loc[:, "DATE"] = df.DATE.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
```

Not at a computer so I can't test but I think that should do it.

Comment: The second line gives me "ValueError: year=1700 is before 1900; the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1900"