# pandas SettingWithCopyWarning, returning view vs copy

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am quite confused about when a `SettingWithCopyWarning` is raised. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df0 = pd.DataFrame([["Fruit", "Apple", 12, 0.3],
                    ["Fruit", "Orange", 23, 0.2],
                    ["Dairy", "Milk", 4, 1],
                    ["Dairy", "Cheese", 1.0, 9.5],
                    ["Meat", "Pork", 8, 11],
                    ["Meat", "Buffalo", 2, 18],
                    ["Fruit", "Strawberry", 45, 2.2]],
                   columns=["Type", "Item", "Quantity", "Price"])

df1 = df0.loc[df0.loc[:, "Price"] < 10, ["Type", "Item", "Price"]]  # a copy(?)
df2 = df0.loc[df0.loc[:, "Price"] < 10]  # also a copy, but maybe this is not always the case?

df1.loc[1, "Item"] = "Banana"  # works fine
df2.loc[1, "Item"] = "Banana"  # raises SettingWithCopyWarning
```

It seems that `df1` is always a copy, whereas, `df2` is not always a copy (this time `df0`does not change though). Why does this happen? I am more interested in understanding the reason than avoiding the warning itself. I read [pandas' documentation on view vs copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy), but it is not too enlightening on what `loc` returs. Quoting:

> dfmi.loc is guaranteed to be dfmi itself with modified indexing behavior

and immediately afterwards:

> Of course, dfmi.loc.__ getitem__(idx) may be a view or a copy of dfmi

I saw many interesting discussions, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002762/pandas-settingwithcopywarning), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724378/pandas-settingwithcopywarning), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147027/action-with-pandas-settingwithcopywarning) (and a few more), but none provides a reproducable example and none actually explains what happens when `.loc` is used. I saw that sometimes false positives can exist and that there are some workarounds (turn off warning, set `.is_copy = False`), but these fail to actively tackle the problem.

Any insight? Why is it ok to modify `df1` but not `df2`?