# Map new column by range of values with pandas.series.between()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, range

I'm, trying to to add a new column to my df that will be mapped by ranges of other column in the same df. I'm using `pandas.series.between()` function to define the new values but getting an error:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'

This is what I have tried:

```
my_dict = {df['column'].between(0.0, 5.0) : 1,
                  df['column'].between(5.1, 7.0) : 2,
                  df['column'].between(7.1, 10.0) : 3,
                  df['column'].between(10.1, 13.0) : 4,
                  df['column'].between(13.1, 16.0) : 5,
                  df['column'].between(19.1, 22.0) : 6,
                  df['column'].between(22.1, 25.0) : 7,
                  df['column'].between(25.1, 28.0) : 8,
                  df['column'].between(28.1, 31.0) : 9,
                  df['column'].between(31.1, 34.0) : 10,
                  df['column'].between(34.1, 37.0) : 11,
                  df['column'].between(37.1, 40.0) : 12,
                  df['column'].between(40.1, df['column'].max()) : 13
                 }


df['new_column'] = df.map(my_dict)
```

If there's any other way to do that without s.bewtween() it will be also a good option.

Comment: You can use `np.select()`

Comment: please provide a sample of the dataframe

Comment: I found an answer with pd.cut() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151071/how-to-encode-a-range-of-values-using-pandas

Answer (score 0):

We can directly use df.apply

```
def map_function(x):
   if 0.0<= x <=5        : return 1
   elif 5.1<=x<=7.0      : return 2
   elif 7.1<= x <=10.0   : return 3
   elif 10.1<= x <=13.0  : return 4
   elif 13.1<=x <= 16.0  : return 5
   elif 16.1<=x<=19.0    :return  6
   elif 19.1<=x<=22.0    :return  7
   elif 22.1<=x<=25.0    :return  8
   elif 25.1<=x<=28.0    :return  9
   elif 28.1<=x<=31.0    :return  10
   elif 31.1<=x<=34.0    :return  11
   elif 34.1<=x<=37.0    :return  12
   elif 37.1<= x <=40.0  :return  13
   elif x >40.0: return 14
df['new_column']=df['column'].apply(map_function)
```

Note : In the ranges you mentioned, you missed a bracket -(16-19)`elif 16.1<=x<=19.0    :return  6` Assuming that it was bymistake I took liberty to add that range.
If Missing the range(16-19) was intentional then make changes accordingly for the map_function.